# Write tclsh script to compile SV file by VCS tool

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I am writing a tclsh script to compile system verilog files, how can I solve the problem below and compile all the files in tclsh script?

The command below will only compile 'mod1.sv':

```
exec vlogan -sverilog mod1.sv mod2.sv mod3.sv
```

The command below will only compile 'mod2.sv':

```
exec vlogan -sverilog mod2.sv mod3.sv mod1.sv
```

But this actually compile all the sv file in command line:

```
vlogan -sverilog mod2.sv mod3.sv mod1.sv
```

Comment: How about `eval exec vlogan -sverilog mod2.sv mod3.sv mod1.sv` ?

Comment: Dinesh, this really work for me... thanks....
Why a "eval" will solve the problem?

Comment: `eval` will concatenate all the args and then it will be evaluated. Have a look at the [man](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm) page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tcl version >= 8.5 you could as well use list expansion via {*}

```
exec vlogan -sverilog {*}{mod1.sv mod2.sv mod3.sv}
```

if you stored the file names beforehand it would be

```
set svFiles [list mod1.sv mod2.sv mod3.sv]
exec vlogan -sverilog {*}$svFiles
```

I like learning by example. If you do as well this might be helpful: [Examples summarizing various methods of exec](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1039#pagetoce83e35d8)